# iLO and DNS - how does it work?

Tags: domain-name-system, ilo

How does host name resolution work on a server's iLO port? For example, in case of a HP ProLiant server equipped with iLO, I can access the iLO web interface through a factory-set hostname URL http://ILOCZJ12345S1.

I know the ILO board received a local IP address via DHCP, but my local DNS server tells me it doesn't know ILOCZJ12345S1. So how do they do it? Is WINS involved, perhaps?

Comment: Do a wireshark, surelly netbios/wins, so I guess you are on the same network segment as the iLO card to have it work.

Answer (score 1):

ILO DNS requires that Dynamic DNS be set up (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3007) so that the ILO can tell your DNS what its hostname is based on the IP that the DHCP server just gave it.

How this is set up depends a lot on exactly what DNS server software you are using. This related topic on how to set this up without allowing just anyone to insert DNS records could be useful:

[What are the practical risks of enabling the unsecure DNS updates on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/732550/what-are-the-practical-risks-of-enabling-the-unsecure-dns-updates-on-windows/732557)